# How to access more than 10 products in Amazon mws via ListMatchingProducts API using node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, meteor, npm, amazon-mws

I am using node.js(Meteor) for calling **Amazon MWS ListMatchingProducts API** for getting all **products** of my seller account . Its running sucessfully and i am getting the response , but as the documentation said that **only ten(10) products are returned at one time**. So i just want to know how we get products more than 10 . **In the doc Amazon also said that you can submit NextToken with a "ByNextToken" operation to request additional pages.But i am not getting any nextToken or related to that nextToken field on my response**.So how do i get the nextToken from there side or how can i get more than 10 products from that API. As i also check on one post they said that we need to use Reports for that but i want to use ListMatchingProducts API for that and want result more than 10.

Please provide me any suggestion or guidance how can i achieve that.

Any help would be appriciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to call the [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_Overview.html) using the `Inventory Report` report type or one of the other [Listing Report types](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__ListingsReports).  That is the way to go.  The `ListMatchingProducts`operation of the [Products API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/products/index.html) is meant to be a search, based on a query.  Yes, it only lists ten products but it does not give you a NextToken like some of the other operations.  Knowing your Report Type and Marketplace ID, you can submit those to the Reports API with your credentials and get back all of your products all at once and there is no searching involved.

What I would also suggest is to use the [Amazon Scratchpad](https://mws.amazonservices.com/scratchpad/index.html) to play around with your operations to make sure you get what you expect, then plug it into your node.js project.

Comment: Thanks for speedy response. As you suggested to use Amazon Scratchpad but there is a required field i.e MWSAuthToken but i don't get any MWSAuthToken while registering my app so would appriciate if you please let me know from where and how can i get MWSAuthToken.

Comment: Read about it here: https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/faq.html#mawsportal-faq-mwsCredentials

Comment: I tried to go with link you specified but as i click on the link i.e Visit the User Permissions page on Seller Central.https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/account-manager/home.html/ref=au_userperms_dnav_home_ it will say that   **Sorry, you are not an authorized Seller Central user**    but when i was  registered first i get sellerId, marketplaceId , developer account number, aws key and secret key but not got MwsAuthToken.   Thanks

Comment: The owner of the seller central account has to go and request to give their developer (you) access to the seller central account.  This process will give you the MWSAuthToken.  See this link http://support.pipemonk.com/support/solutions/articles/11000007468-getting-your-amazon-seller-id-and-mws-auth-token